# How to get content type data on basis of assigned taxonomy?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I want to get the data of particular content type on the basis of taxonomy assigned to it. How can I get this using query.

```
$bloglist = db_select('node', 'n')
                    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
                    ->condition('type', 'product_list', '=')
                    ->condition('status', 1, '=')
                    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
                    ->execute()
                    ->fetchCol();

        // Get all of the article nodes.
        $bloglists2 = node_load_multiple($bloglist);
```

I have this query to get the data for `product_list` content type. Now I want to add one more condition of taxonomy to get data on basis of taxonomy and content type. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7) class was built to do pretty much exactly that:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product_list')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_foo', 'tid', $term_id)
  ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
  ->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
}
```

Comment: What should I write instead of `field_foo`? I have the `$term_id` value

Comment: The machine name of the field attached to the node type, you can find it in the Manage Fields admin page

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Join statement; what you basically need to do is joining your query with another from another table.

Here is an example that you can use.

`$query = db_select('file_managed', 'fm');
$query->join('field_data_field_image', 'fi', 'fm.fid = fi.field_image_fid');
$query->groupBy('fm.fid');
$query->fields('fm', array('filename', 'uri'));
$query->fields('fi', array('field_image_width', 'field_image_height'));
$query->condition('fi.bundle','image_for_slider','=');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();`

In this example, the file_managed table is joined with field_data_field_image; 
you have to switch those with node and field_tags.